# IN SQL, how can I add a constraint to future INSERT statements for a table?

Tags: sql, database, db2, constraints

Say I have the following table:

```
Name    Age
____________
Bob     33
Jow     23
Cindy   29
Mary    22
Phil    98
```

I want to Add a constraint to this table, such that all future INSERT statements to this list of people must have the age of the person being inserted be over 45. How can I accomplish this?

I'm using DB2, by the way.

Comment: @Waffles: why do you want to do this? Can you give an example of where this would be a good idea?

Comment: @Waffles: this makes no sense in a database. Don't try to learn SQL by using nonsense examples.

Comment: @Waffles - The obvious solution is to correct the data and then add the constraint. Even if we provide a solution, you will be violating the least astonishment rule for other developers when they find rows in the table that violate the check constraint.

Comment: @John: Tune it down a knotch, you're not being helpful at all. It's not even that crazy of a requirement... New company policy, you must be over 45 to be accepted; however, a grandfather clause exists on existing members who don't meet this new requirement. That said, my example is best enforced in the application rather than the DB, so you do have a point.

Comment: @matt: I don't understand. Who are you? What is "my example"? I don't believe I was talking to you, unless you are also "Waffles".

Comment: @matt.dolfin - I disagree. Any policy based on the age of the person would not affect the age of the person themselves. Instead, the birth date of the person should be stored and the rule altered to accommodate the change which would then affect everyone. If it is to be restricted to people hired before a certain time, then the rule could be expanded to handle that. Either way, there is, as yet, no viable scenario where you would want a check constraint of the nature requested.

Comment: Well, wow. I really didn't expect so much discussion over a question like this. I really had no intention of starting debate over this request - I was really just curious as per how a constraint can be added to a table after it's creation, so I made up a silly little example above after some google searches turned out to be rather fruitless. In the future, I'll be sure to ground my questions in reality.

Comment: @Waffles, sorry man. This is just getting silly. You did nothing wrong.

Comment: @Waffles - I think the point we are trying to raise is that having such a requirement indicates a systemic flaw in the design. It is akin to asking how to improve the speed of a car with square wheels. The obvious first step is to use round wheels as opposed to looking elsewhere. In this case, the obvious solution is to change the way that age is stored to use a birth date instead of a calculated value. Doing that eliminates the need for the check constraint of the nature you requested.

Comment: John, my example that you are asking about is one sentence above the words "my example" that you quoted. He just wants to learn how to add constraints. Thomas, you are absolutely correct. Age wouldn't really ever be even stored in a DB unless maybe it was the age a person was when something happened? idk, it is not a realistic example. Waffles, I posted an answer with my thoughts on what I would do if a constraint was necessary that didn't exist before. Sorry for the trouble. Happy programming!

Comment: @matt: I would have said, "this example" to refer to an example within the same comment. When you said, "my example", I thought you were referring to some example I hadn't seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I really had to do it, I could add CreationDate to this table and add constraint:

```
alter table table_name add constraint age_check check 
((age > 18) or (creation_date < '2011-02-12'))
```

That is probably not what you want, but it is the best way to describe your rule: 'From 2011-02-12 we allow only > 18 people to be registered'. Changed 45 to 18, because it makes more sense:)

Comment: @Luk: I would argue that such a change should imply two tables: one without the constraint containing the rows that now violate the constraint, and one with the constraint containing no rows that violate the constraint. Perhaps with a view to join them.

Comment: @John Saunders: Imagine this is system user table. Would you really split it into 2 different tables? What about referential integrity? What about performance? This is really basic check constraint and your solution is huge decision, that can influence huge part of the system.

Comment: @Luk: tell me again the reason for changing the constraint part-way through? A database constraint, mind you, not a business rule. Not "we only register people age 45 or older", but rather, "people age 45 or older cannot exist as registered users".

Comment: @John Saunders: Can't you enforce business rules on database level, as constraints? It can be additional protection. Of course it shouldn't be the main place to enforce this rule.

Comment: @Luk: I prefer to enforce the "stringent" rules as constraints: "a registered user can never, under any circumstances, be under age 45", as opposed to "a registered user should never be under age 45, and should be rejected if an attempt is made to register such a user". Using a constraint makes some rows valid, and other rows not valid, simply because of when they were entered into the database. Hence, my suggestion of two tables.

Comment: @John Saunders: The rule is "A registered user can't be under age of 45, unless he was registered before 2011-02-12". This check constraint doesn't make any rows invalid. Are you against using CHECK constraints?

Comment: @Luk: I'm against artificially introducing constraints like this simply because the rules changed in such a manner. However, since this wasn't an actual requirement, there's no real point in us discussing it. Let's continue this discussion the next time we have a real requirement to disagree on.

Answer (score 1):

I see 4 options:

1. Fix the table to meet the requirement (if it makes sense to do so), then [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275462%28SQL.80%29.aspx) ... ADD CONSTRAINT
2. [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275462%28SQL.80%29.aspx) ... WITH NOCHECK
   ... ADD CONSTRAINT (this will not allow you to change or insert a record without meeting the constraint, but will leave existing records alone.)
3. [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) ... AFTER INSERT ... (this would only check new inserts.)
4. Don't enforce this in the Database.
   (Since this is just a learning
   example, this doesn't really help
   you.)

LukLed's answer is an alternative to #3. It might be a better one since it simplifies things and makes it clear that the constraint is a new one as of a certain date.

Comment: No, a constraint like that should be in the database. It applies to all new employees, regardless of the application used to enter them.

Comment: Thanks Catcall, I removed that note.